# Copy multiple cell values to clipboard on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Javascript. I would like to create the following:

1. A cell in a row in column 1 in a table is clicked. In my example Cell1.
2. Cell2 and Cell3 will be copied to clipboard, but not Cell4.
3. They will be separated by a "-",

Example:

**"Cell1" is clicked. This will be copied to clipboard: "Cell2 - Cell3".**

I have been trying for hours but can't quite figure out the JS.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Example table:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell1</td>
      <td>Cell2</td>
      <td>Cell3</td>
      <td>Cell4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, it is a bit newish javascript.

I used [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) array functions

```js
const cells = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr td')]

function getOtherCells(e) {
 const otherCells = cells.filter(cell => e.target !== cell);
 const text = otherCells.reduce((acc, cell, idx) => {
   return idx===0? `${cell.innerText}`:`${acc} - ${cell.innerText}`;
 }, "");
 console.log(text)
}

cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener("click", getOtherCells))
```

```css
th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CellOne</td>
      <td>CellTwo</td>
      <td>CellThree</td>
      <td>CellFour</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Welcome on board and I hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I tested your script as is. Upon clicking any cell in the table it put the complete table (all cells, all columns) into the log, not just the 2 cells I'd like.

I'm sorry, maybe I was not clear in explaining what I want:
When a cell in a row in column 1 is clicked it will copy the text in the same row in column 2 and 3, but not column 4. Clicking in any other cell besides column 1 would in this case do nothing.

I will keep trying with your script, maybe I can get it to work. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
    <input type = "text" id="txt">
    <input type = "button " id ="btn" value ="copy" onclick="copyTxt('txt')">
</div>
<div>
    <input type = "text" id="txt1">
    <input type = "button " id ="btn1" value ="copy" onclick="copyTxt('txt1')">
</div>
<div>
    <input type = "text" id="txt2">
    <input type = "button " id ="btn2" value ="copy" onclick="copyTxt('txt2')">
</div>
<script>
    function copyTxt(id){
        document.getElementById(id).select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }
</script>
```